# How to exclude fields within an object on a specific JAX - RS call?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following `Java` Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private String id;

    private String name = "";

    private String score = "";
}
```

There are currently 3 `REST` calls within my application, 2 of which will send all 3 fields within the `Person` object

However in my 3rd call I cannot send the "score" field within the object.

Is there a JAX-RS functionality to exclude this field for this one specific call?

Current `JAX-RS` Code:

```
if (person != null) {
            return ResponseBuilder.anOKResponse().withEntity(person).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseBuilder.notFound().withEntity(PERSON_IS_NULL_ERROR).build();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app runs on weblogic, then your rest app is based on Jersey which uses moxy as the default message body reader and writer. Please see this blog for detail info to solve your problems.
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html